# Retrieve data from mysql and show in html table

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have a table "data" , in that I have a column "name"
there are many names saved in name column in the table name "data"
NOW what I want is print out the record some thing like this but using PHP `mysql_fetch_array()` and loop through it. (while loop)

Results:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>name</td><td>name</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Edit: Here is my current code -

```
<ul class="spa1" style="margin-left:5px">
<?php               

        $img= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM immi");
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($img)){
            echo "<li><a href='PracticeArea.php?cat=ts&id=".$row['id']."'>".$row['name']."</a></li>";
            }?>

</ul>
```

and what I want is something like this:

```
<ul class="spa1" style="margin-left:5px">
<?php               

        $img= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM immi");
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($img)){
 echo "<li><a href='PracticeArea.php?cat=ts&id=".$row['id']."'>".$row['name']."</a></li>
<li><a href='PracticeArea.php?cat=ts&id=".$row['id'] + 1."'>".$row['name']."</a></li>
";
            }?>
```

Comment: Currently your question is pretty broad.  You will find that it is much easier to get help if you show what you have tried so far and what the results were.

Comment: Sir I have been tried it and I am succeeded to show a name per table row but I need to show two names(table data (td) ) per one row dynamically using while loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table><tr>
<?php
$i = 0;
$img = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM immi");
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($img)) {
  if (($i % 2) == 0 && $i > 0) echo '</tr><tr>';
    echo "<td><a href='PracticeArea.php?cat=ts&id=".$row['id']."'>".$row['name']."</a></td>";
  ++$i;
  }
if (($i % 2) == 1) echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
?>
</tr></table>
```

Comment: thank you so much its almost done but what i want is a new row(table-tr) starts after showing two table data(table-td)

Comment: go to my website its... http://www.kassmanlawoffices.com/ .. now when you go to main menu Practice Area -> Traffic Ticket Lawyer -> you will see each time its making new row and insert one data what I want is ...It starts a row and put two data (data1 and next two it (data2)) and then end up row

Comment: I cannot find what you want me to see. Nevertheless I can assure you that my code does exactly what you say. Maybe you made another mistake? You can post your code in your original question, so that we can take a look.

Comment: By the way, do you know that your website looks totally broken in a browser window with less than 1215px width?